# If f is twice differentiable, prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)- 2 f(c) + f(c-h)}{h}=f''(c)$ for $f:(a,b) \to R$ , $c \in (a,b)$.

Tags: calculus

> If f is twice differentiable, prove that $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)- 2 f(c) + f(c-h)}{h^2}=f''(c)$$ for $f:(a,b) \to \Bbb R$ , $c \in (a,b)$.

I am trying to start from the RHS and get to the LHS , I was able to prove LHS=RHS using L hospital. This was my progress so far:
$$\lim_{a\to 0}{\frac{f'(c+a)-f'(c)}{a}}=\lim_{a\to 0}{\frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\left[\frac{f(c+a+h)-f(c+a)}{h}-\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\right]}{a}}$$ But I don't really know if you could form them into a  single limit  , or anything else. And what to do after.

PS: I'm in highschool, so I won't be able to understand  solutions involving undergraduate math, like real analysis, etc.

Edit 1: replaced h with $h^2$.

Edit 2: was able to start from lhs to go towards rhs but not the other way around.

Comment: Doesn’t this look like $$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{[f(c+h)-f(c)]+[f(c-h)-f(c)]}{h}=2f’(c)?$$

Comment: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f{c+h)- f(c-h)}{h} = 2 f'(c)$$ if i recall correctly.

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital's Rule?  If so, apply it to to the limit expression that appears in the title (you need $h^2$ in the denominator, not $h$).  What do you find?  Now apply once more.

Comment: The statement is incorrect. The limit is $2f'(c)$, as pointed out in the first comment.

Comment: See: "Taylor polynomial" in your calculus textbook.

Comment: @insipidintegrator It can and does happen twice since the correct denominator is $h^2$, not  $h$.

Comment: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c-h)- f(c)}{-h} = f'(c)$$, @insipidintegrator so the formula you used was for:$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)- f(c-h)}{h} = 2 \cdot f'(c)$$

Comment: replaced, h with $h^2$. sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Does the alleged duplicate really answer this question?

Comment: @GEdgar How does the new "alleged duplicate" sound?

Comment: Okay, i could use the Left hand side expression, ie : $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)- 2 f(c) + f(c-h)}{h^2}$$ to equate to f''(x) by Lhospital. But if i as to derive if from first principle, how do i get f''(x) in the form of that, ie start from right hand side, and equate it towards the left.

Comment: @MarkViola ... The new one is better.  But not perfect.  The "asymptotic expansion" used by user21820 is a good way to do this.  [But the proof of it given there requires $f''(x)$ exists for $x$ near $c$.  Instead, you could cite Taylor's theorem, requiring only that $f''(c)$ exist at that one point.]

Comment: @GEdgar Hi Edgar.  I believe that L'Hospital's Rule is the better way to go, especially given that this is a high school student.

Comment: @q123LsaB Applying LHR twice, we find that $$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x-h)}{2h}\\\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f''(x+h)+f''(x-h)}{2}\\\\&=f''(x)\end{align}$$.

Comment: @MarkViola mhm, i was able to use L hospital to from the expression, after the comments suggested so. I wanted to know if you could start from f"(x) and end up to the lhs expression

Comment: I think one can do$$\begin{align*}f''(c)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(c+h)-f'(c)}h\\[1ex]&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+2h)-f(c+h)}h-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h\right)\\[1ex]&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+2h)-2f(c+h)+f(c)}{h^2}\\[1ex]&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c^*+h)-2f(c^*)+f(c^*-h)}{h^2}\end{align*}$$where $c^*=c+h$ in the last line. I'd like to hear any reasons why this doesn't work if one cannot.

Comment: @user170231 your second equation is wrong. The term in brackets does not depend on $h$ anymore, so you have something like $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\cdot c$

Comment: @user170231 - Your big mistake is $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(c+h)-f'(c)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\lim_{h_1\to0}\frac{f(c+h+h_1)-f(c+h)}{h_1}-\lim_{h_2\to0}\frac{f(c+h_2)-f(c)}{h_2}\right)$$ The three separate limits each have their own variable. You have to justify combining the separate limits into a single limit. Just using the same letter for the dummy variables is not enough.

Comment: Right, thank you both for pointing that out. I suppose we can invoke the property $D(f+g)=Df+Dg$ to write$$f'(c+h)-f'(c)=(f(c+h)-f(c))'=\lim_{h_1\to0}\frac{(f(c+h+h_1)-f(c+h_1))-(f(c+h)-f(c))}{h_1}$$to eliminate one of the limit variables but that doesn't seem too helpful.